# retrieve the id of a selected listview item to a php page java script et jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i use a jQuery mobile and html5 and i want to have the id of a selected item in my listview(dynamic) and sent it in a detail .php, please i need a help this my  ^page sript try:

```
                        output += '<li><a href="#detail" onclick="affichedetail()">'+    field.nom + '</a></li><li>'+field.dist+'KM</li><li><img src="' + './photo/' + field.photo + '" height="100" width="100"</img></li><li>Latitude:' + field.lat + '</li><li>Longitude:' +        field.longitude + '</li><li>Aprés:' + delai2 + '</li>';

                // alert(var1);
                //  alert(var2);


                    });
                    $('#mosquee').html(output).listview("refresh");
                    // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                });
```

and this my page detail.php?requete=""

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","priere");
  // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
      $result="";
       $valeur = $_GET['requete'];
     print("id="+$valeur);
         $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT lat,longitude FROM mosque where  id=$valeur");
       while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
            $json[] = $row;
         }
        //json_encode( $json );
           echo json_encode($json);
    echo "<table border='1'>
           <tr>
          <th>lat</th>
         <th>Longitude</th>
        </tr>";

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lat'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['longitude'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
         }
         echo "</table>";


          mysqli_close($con);
      ?>
```

i want to send the id of a selected item in my page detail .php,because in want to show the detail of the item selected.How i can know my id item selected in my listview and how send it in url to detail.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the ID in the "output" variable that holds the html and change your "affichedetail()" function to either take a parameter and you can call it by affichedetail(ID#) directly?

Also if you use jQuery, i'd recommend dropping the onclick tag and just using 
$(".detailClassOfYourChoice").on('click',function() { /*your code here*/ });

Comment: $(".detailClassOfYourChoice"  what the purpose of this function?

Comment: how i can retrieve the id of my selected item?

Comment: Go to jQuery.com and read about jQuery selectors to understand what i meant and if you put the ID# in the html as a rel="" attribute, you can get it in jQuery with $(this).attr('rel') within the click function.